# FFMPEG stream to multiples servers using the same -filter_complex options

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, stream, streaming, rtmp

I want to stream a video to two rtmp servers, I have some options like scaling the resolution from 1080p to 576p or adding a logo. These options are serving in the first rtmp server  which the signal was sent, but in the second rtmp it is sending 1080p without any of these options, what am I doing wrong?

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4 -i video.mp4 -i hello.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=1650:950,scale=1024:576" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://test -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://test2
```

Answer (score -1):

Unlike input streams, you can only consume a filtergraph output stream only once, and the first rtmp output is snatching it up. If you want to use it on both outputs, split the output of the filter:

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4 \
-i video.mp4 -i hello.jpg \
-filter_complex "overlay=1650:950,scale=1024:576,split=2[v1][v2]" \
-map [v1] -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k \
-f flv rtmp://test \
-map [v2] -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k \
-acodec aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://test2
```

Another, likely preferred, option if you are outputting identical streams is to use `tee` muxer. It should look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4 \
-i video.mp4 -i hello.jpg \
-filter_complex "overlay=1650:950,scale=1024:576[vout]" \
-map [vout] -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k \
-f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://test|[f=flv] rtmp://test2"
```

Comment: Using the two examples you've given me I'm getting this error "Output with label '0:a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere."

Comment: oops, it should be `0:a` not `[0:a]`

Comment: Works !!! you are awesome, thanks a lot for u big help my friend !

Comment: So a last question, If you had to add something to improve the performance of that line so as not to consume so much CPU, what would you add

Comment: The second option should be the way to go (as it encodes only once). Other than that, no idea (I don't do streaming). I'm sure you can google to get more info tho.

Comment: sorry for write again but in the second option im getting this "frame= 3164 fps= 47 q=23.0 size=N/A time=00:01:46.11 bitrate=N/A dup=2 drop=0 speed=1.57x" Bitrate N/A, no video, ¿is normal?

Comment: tbh, i do not know. are the streams working?

Comment: is working but no video.